# Nightwatch Error on Retrieving New Session

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

I didn't have this problem before my computer was updated from Windows 7 to Windows 10.

When I try to run my nightwatch test with firefox I get this error:

```
Running:  Sending, Watching, and Sharing a Demo
INFO Request: POST /wd/hub/session
- data:  {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"firefox","javascriptEnabled":true,"acceptSslCerts":true,"platform":"ANY","name":"Complete\\sales\\sales Test1"}}
 - headers:  {"Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Content-Length":151}
ERROR Response 500 POST /wd/hub/session (3319ms) { state: 'unhandled error',
  sessionId: null,
  hCode: 33496070,
  value:
   { localizedMessage: '127.0.0.1:7055 failed to respond',
     cause: null,
     suppressed: [],
     message: '127.0.0.1:7055 failed to respond',
     hCode: 10341065,
     class: 'org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException',
     screen: null },
  class: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response',
  status: 13 }

Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server

Connection refused! Is selenium server started?
{ state: 'unhandled error',
  sessionId: null,
  hCode: 33496070,
  value:
   { localizedMessage: '127.0.0.1:7055 failed to respond',
     cause: null,
     suppressed: [],
     message: '127.0.0.1:7055 failed to respond',
     hCode: 10341065,
     class: 'org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException',
     screen: null },
  class: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response',
  status: 13 }
```

My selenium debug log lists:

```
11:08:52.724 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
Setting system property webdriver.chrome.driver to bin/chromedriver
11:08:52.786 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.91-b15
11:08:52.786 INFO - OS: Windows 10 10.0 x86
11:08:52.802 INFO - v2.51.0, with Core v2.51.0. Built from revision 1af067d
11:08:52.849 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
11:08:52.849 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
11:08:52.849 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=, platform=MAC}] does not match the current platform WIN10
11:08:52.948 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
11:08:52.948 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
11:08:53.427 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{acceptSslCerts=true, name=Complete\sales\sales Test1, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platform=ANY}]])
11:08:53.437 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{acceptSslCerts=true, name=Complete\sales\sales Test1, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platform=ANY}]
11:08:56.532 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.51.0', revision: '1af067d', time: '2016-02-05 19:15:17'
System info: host: 'StudioXPS', ip: '10.0.0.46', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSession.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:202)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:164)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:130)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler.java:680)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:571)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1526)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1479)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:920)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:358)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:537)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.51.0', revision: '1af067d', time: '2016-02-05 19:15:17'
System info: host: 'StudioXPS', ip: '10.0.0.46', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.callConstructor(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.newInstance(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.callConstructor(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:91)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.51.0', revision: '1af067d', time: '2016-02-05 19:15:17'
System info: host: 'StudioXPS', ip: '10.0.0.46', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:129)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: 127.0.0.1:7055 failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:90)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.execute(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:160)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:380)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
    ... 19 more
11:08:56.548 WARN - Exception: 127.0.0.1:7055 failed to respond
```

I have tried running the test through selenium standalone versions:

- 2.53.0
- 2.52.0
- 2.51.0

And since the latest firefox version (47.0.1) might not work, I've also tried with 46.0.1.

None of these have fixed the issue. Is there some way to fix this, or will I need to go back to windows 7?

Comment: Actually, if I remember correctly, I was able to run the test once after upgrading to windows 10, so that probably isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and by adding:

```
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "browserName": "firefox",
    "javascriptEnabled": true,
    "acceptSslCerts": true
  },
```

to the test_settings made my build worked